# Hadoop: slaves in service but doing nothing at all

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I set up a hadoop cluster and started a MapReduce job on the cluster.

The master node is running actively but all slaves are doing nothing at all.

`JPS` on the slave node produces

```
20390 DataNode
20492 NodeManager
21256 Jps
```

Here is the screen cast:

[image: The master is running]

The next to last row corresponds to the master node.

So why the slaves using no blocks?

Also running `top` on master node yields the Java process(`hadoop jar jar-file.jar args`) taking almost 100% of CPU resources. However, such process does not exist on any slave machines.

That is why I think slaves are at rest, doing nothing at all.

Here is one example of the slave datanode log:

```
2014-07-24 23:28:01,302 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlockMap
2014-07-24 23:28:01,302 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2014-07-24 23:28:01,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.5% max memory 889 MB = 4.4 MB
2014-07-24 23:28:01,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^19 = 524288 entries
2014-07-24 23:28:01,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Periodic Block Verification Scanner initialized with interval 504 hours for block pool BP-1752077220-193.167.138.8-1406217332464
2014-07-24 23:28:01,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Added bpid=BP-1752077220-193.167.138.8-1406217332464 to blockPoolScannerMap, new size=1
2014-07-24 23:31:01,116 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DirectoryScanner: BlockPool BP-1752077220-193.167.138.8-1406217332464 Total blocks: 0, missing metadata files:0, missing block files:0, missing blocks in memory:0, mismatched blocks:0
```

And nothing more.

However, for the master data node, the log file contains lines like the following:

```
2014-07-24 22:27:23,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1752077220-193.167.138.8-1406217332464:blk_1073742749_1925 src: /193.167.138.8:44210 dest: /193.167.138.8:50010
```

which I think means the node is receiving tasks and processing the data.

The following is from the yarn log file of one the slave node:

```
2014-07-24 23:28:13,811 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8042
2014-07-24 23:28:13,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app /node started at 8042
2014-07-24 23:28:14,122 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2014-07-24 23:28:14,130 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ugluk/193.167.138.8:8031
2014-07-24 23:28:14,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registering with RM using finished containers :[]
2014-07-24 23:28:14,366 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.security.NMContainerTokenSecretManager: Rolling master-key for container-tokens, got key with id 1336429163
2014-07-24 23:28:14,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInNM: Rolling master-key for nm-tokens, got key with id :1986181585
2014-07-24 23:28:14,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registered with ResourceManager as shagrat.hiit.fi:48662 with total resource of <memory:8192, vCores:8>
2014-07-24 23:28:14,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Notifying ContainerManager to unblock new container-requests
```

I am using Hadoop 2.4.0

Comment: Are you getting any error while running the job? Where could you see that nodes are at rest?

Comment: @charlesbabbage, slaves are actually not receiving the jobs, I think. I added information on the log files, hope that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you formatted namenode more than once.

The block pool id error is majorly due to formatting of namenode multiple times.

Every time ,you format a namenode ,the blockpool id ,cluster id and the namespace id changes.

So first check the above attributes of the namenode and other datanodes and secondary namenode.

You can check using VERSION file in current directory of these nodes.For this ,first see where you configured your node by checking its path hadoop hdfs-site.xml.

go to that path,and look for the CURRENT directory and make the necessary changes.

Please let me know if this helps.